# How to convert the timestamp date format to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I want to convert this timestamp format `2021-04-21T17:00:50` to "dd/MM/YYYY"

I'm getting **number format exception**:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
private String courseStartDate = null;
long longDate = 2021-04-21T17:00:50; 

courseStartDate = getDateTimeFromTimeStamp(longDate, DATE_FORMAT);

public String getDateTimeFromTimeStamp(Long time, String mDateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(mDateFormat);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date dateTime = new Date(time);
    return dateFormat.format(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: In my Eclipse I get *Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements* in the line `long longDate = 2021-04-21T17:00:50;`. Could you please post post a [mre] showing exactly how to reproduce the error you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
LocalDateTime
.parse( "2021-04-21T17:00:50" )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
)
```

This has been covered many many times. So [search to learn more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern+java+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: Very much thanks.  This format  ( 2021-04-21T17:00:50) is timestamp or not ??

Comment: Also covered many many times on Stack Overflow. That format is standard ISO 8601 format. But that text is *not* a timestamp in that it does not represent a specific point on the timeline. Determining a point on the timeline requires the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.